# Adding values to landuse class raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, land-cover, land-classification

I am currently working on a map that holds my animals' projected radio-locations from my work this summer.
I have a current land class map downloaded from the USGS of the site; however, some of the pixels classifications wash over certain classes that are present within the field.

For instance, I am working with turtles that frequent a vernal pool and a watering hole. Within the map, there is no value for those landclass features in those locations present within the map. They are instead just a part of the larger surrounding landclass "i.e., deciduous forest, or scrub/shrub".

How do I delineate these areas and add them to my landuse class feature raster file?

Comment: So the Land class-map already has a class for deciduous forest, and you would like to correct them with vernal pool and watering hole class?

Comment: Start by mapping your new landuse features (vernal pools, etc.) as vector features if there isn't an existing vernal pools layer. High resolution imagery might be really helpful for this, as something you could trace if you don't have field survey measurements of these pools. Then you can use these vernal pool features to do some kind of reclassification or union with the existing landuse layer.